# Why the code did not run with facet wrap function

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to convert my plots into percentages. I also wanted to include the facet wrap function. Without that line, the plot seems to be working. Kindly suggest the changes to be made to the code. The error obtained is as follows:
Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Building.Age`.

- Plot is missing `Building.Age`
- Layer 1 is missing `Building.Age`
- Layer 2 is missing `Building.Age`

```r
   data %>% 
     count(Locality.Division = factor(Locality.Division), Number.of.Beetle = factor(Number.of.Beetle)) %>% 
     mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x = Locality.Division, y = pct, fill = Number.of.Beetle, label = scales::percent(pct))) + 
     geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
     geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
               vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
               size = 3) + 
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
     facet_wrap(~Building.Age)+
     labs(title = "Comparison between Number of beetle, Locality division and Age of the building",subtitle ="Building age") 
#> Error in data %>% count(Locality.Division = factor(Locality.Division), : could not find function "%>%"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you don't have the package `magrittr` loaded. This is where the pipe operator `%>%` comes from. Try `library(magrittr)`. See [package website](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/) for details if you don't have it installed yet.

Comment: Thanks.But the plot stopped appearing now. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You didn't load the package `dplyr`, so the pipe operator `%>%` isn't understood by **R**. Use `library(dplyr)` to load it.

Comment: I tried uploading the package. But the plot doesn't appear now. Kindly help me.

Comment: I have replaced facet wrap in the 3rd line of code. facet_wrap(~ Building.Age) %>%